# Call a text file and put in an array in python

Tags: python

In a text file abc.txt,  I have written like

```
'abc', 'edf', 'ghij'
```

From my python code, I want to creat an array A such that

```
A=['abc', 'edf', 'ghij']
```

How can I do this?

This is not solving the problem:

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Read the contents of the file into a variable
    AA = file.read()
```

Comment: `A = ast.literal_eval(f'[{AA}]')`

Comment: It would be better to use a standard format like JSON or Pickle to save the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the split method:

```
with open('abc.txt') as file:
    A = file.read().strip("'").split("', '")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is really a CSV file with a single quote as the quote character and with spaces after commas skipped, so a more robust approach would be to use [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to parse the input:

```
import csv

with open('abc.txt') as file:
    A = next(csv.reader(file, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DarkorangeLovableCarrier